# passing form variables into a url with php

Tags: php, url, variables

I have the following form which allows a user to select dates/rooms for a hotel reservation.

```
<form action="booking-form.php" method="post">
  <fieldset>
    <div class="select-date">
      <label>Arrival Date</label>
      <select name="arrd" class="day">
        <option value="1" >1</option>
        ... snip ...
        <option value="24" selected="selected">24</option>
      </select>

      <select name="arrm" class="month">
        <option value="01" >January</option>
        ... snip ...
        <option value="11" selected="selected">November</option>
      </select>
      <select name="arry" class="year">
        <option value="2009" selected="selected">2009</option>
        ... snip ...
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="more">
    <div class="info">
      <label>Days</label>
      <select name="days">
        <option value="1">01</option>
        ... snip ...
        <option value="7" selected="selected">07</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="info">
      <label>Rooms</label>
      <select name="rooms">
        <option value="1">01</option>
        ... snip ...
      </select>
    </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Check availabilty"/>
    <input type="hidden"  name="submitted" value="TRUE"/>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Here is the php which is supposed to process the variables passed from the form and pass them via a url to the booking provider.
Nothing happens when the form is submitted just a white screen with no errors.

```
<?php

 ini_set ('display_errors',1);  
 error_reporting (E_ALL & ~ E_NOTICE);  

 if (isset($_POST['submitted'])){

  $errors = array();

  // A bunch of if's for all the fields and the error messages.


  if (empty($_POST['arrd'])) {
    $errors[] = 'Please select a day';
} else{
    $arrd = ($_POST['arrd']);
}

if (empty($_POST['arrm'])) {
    $errors[] = 'Please select a month';
} else{
    $arrm = ($_POST['arrm']);
}

if (empty($_POST['arry'])) {
    $errors[] = 'Please select a year';
} else{
    $arry = ($_POST['arry']);
}

if (empty($_POST['non'])) {
    $errors[] = 'Please choose a number of nights';
} else{
    $non = ($_POST['non']);
}


if (empty($_POST['norooms'])) {
    $errors[] = 'Please choose a number of rooms';
} else{
    $norooms = ($_POST['norooms']);
}


if (empty($errors)){
$arrdate = $arrd . " " . $arrm ."" . $arry; 

$url ="https://portals.uk.rezlynx.net/DHPPORTAL/wfrmpakquery.aspx?SiteID=DHOLDHALL&arrdate=$arrdate&non=$non&norooms=$norooms";
 header('Location: $url');
exit();

 }

 else{
 foreach($errors as $msg){

 echo"-msg<br/>\n";
 }

 }

 ?>
```

Can anyone see what I am missing?

Thanks in advance..

Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run your code through PHP's lint checker (php -l), you'll see you have a syntax error at line 62 (the last line)

You're simply missing the curly brace that needs to close the initial "if" statement.

Answer (score 3):

The line

```
header('Location: $url');
```

should be

```
header("Location: $url");
```

Variables aren't evaluated within single-quotes.

Comment: +1 from me, but I was only a min or so behind you, wanna +1 me :p

Answer (score 0):

The issue could be

```
header('Location: $url');
exit();
```

Either try

```
header('Location: '.$url);
exit();
```

or

```
header("Location: $url");
exit();
# using the double quotes will parse the $url variable
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use that URL in your form's action attribute and set the method to `GET`?

```
<form action="https://portals.uk.rezlynx.net/DHPPORTAL/wfrmpakquery.aspx?SiteID=DHOLDHALL" method="get">
    [...]
</form>
```

Comment: I never thought of that! - I tried it and got an apache error page. The provider states that the url has to be in the following format...
https://portals.uk.rezlynx.net/DHPPORTAL/wfrmpakquery.aspx?SiteID=DHOLDHALL&arrdate=12/11/2009&non=2&norooms=3 any ideas?

Comment: What exactly does the "wrong" URL look like? I suppose that they either don't get along with additional URL fields passed along (which wouldn't make sense) or that the browser uses a question mark for the first parameter instead of the `&`, which will cause problems, because there's already one parameter in the action URL. In latter case, add the following field to the URL:
`<input type="hidden" name="SiteID" value="DHOLDHALL" />`

Comment: -1 If you use the GET method, the form data will override the query string in your form action